# snapping line nodes to points

Tags: qgis, postgis, snapping

I have a dataset of manholes and pipes; I want to snap the lines start and end nodes to the manholes if they are within a specified distance. Been trying to find away to do this using PostGIS or QGIS because I don't have access to the Arc Desktop tools to do it. I found a post of a similar situation but I cannot get the function to work, I don't know what information is suppose to go where in the expression.

```
    SELECT f.gid as gid,
        ST_Snap(f.Geometry, g.Geometry, 2) as geom
    FROM
        pipe as f,
        (SELECT ST_Collect(Geometry) as Geometry
         FROM mh) as g
```

I thought it was suppose to work like this;

```
            SELECT f.id as gid,
                ST_Snap(f.geom, g.geom, 2) as geom
            FROM
                smains as f,
                (SELECT ST_Collect(geom) as Geometry
                 FROM samh) as g
```

I get column g.geom does not exist, but the column samh.geom does and to my understanding g = samh. When I change it to samh.geom I get missing FROM-clause entry for table "samh" which sounds to me that the variable samh is not defined, but it isn't a variable it is a table.

Comment: Change St_Collect(geom) as Geometry to ST_Collect(geom) as geom.

Comment: I feel so completely stupid for missing that! The query ran so I am hoping it works.

Comment: You want to snap smains to samh with a tolerance of 2? What is your SRID, as a matter of interest. I'm not actually sure that you need ST_Collect. ST_Snap should just chose the nearest geometry, and ST_Collect just bundles geometries together, it doesn't actually transform in the way ST_Union does.

Comment: My SRID is 2954 should be a NAD83 CSRS98 PEI Double Stereographic Projection Metric. I mentioned metric because there is an imperial but it might be NAD27 on the imperial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## John Barca "Change St_Collect(geom) as Geometry to ST_Collect(geom) as geom" Thanks again John.

Edit: This seems to make a selection and doesn't actually update the geometry to snap to the points, still closer to what I want.

Comment: Are you doing select in qgis or postgis , if in postgis you just select data, you do not update it, so add select .. into snapped_table... code